# getActivity() in ArrayAdapter sometimes returns null

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-arrayadapter

I'm occasionally getting a `NullPointerException` in my ArrayAdapter that populates my ListFragment.  It appears that `getActivity()` is returning null, but as far as I can tell it shouldn't do that.

Adapter code `inflater = (LayoutInflater)...` is the exception line:

```
@Override
public View getView( int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent )
{
    view = convertView;

if ( view == null )
{
    /* Inflate a row */
    inflater = (LayoutInflater)getActivity().getSystemService( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE ); // THIS IS THE EXCEPTION LINE
    view = inflater.inflate( R.layout.pairing_list_row, parent, false );
}
```

I'm using a Loader to get the data, and I don't init that until the `onActivityCreated` method.  The adapter isn't created until the loader is finished loading, so it should never happen prior to `onActivityCreated`.

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated( Bundle savedInstanceState )
{
    super.onActivityCreated( savedInstanceState );
    getLoaderManager().initLoader( 0, null, this );
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished( Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor )
{   
    PairingArrayAdapter pairings = (PairingArrayAdapter)getListAdapter();
    if ( pairings == null )
    {
        pairings = new PairingArrayAdapter( getActivity(), R.layout.pairing_list_row );
        setListAdapter( pairings );
    }
    ...
```

Any ideas on what's causing the NullPointerException?  It doesn't happen all the time, it happens once, I do the same thing again and it doesn't happen.  I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've determined that the only possible explanation is that the `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` that I'm using causes `onLoadFinished` to be called when the Fragment is detached in certain circumstances, thus necessitating a check for an attached activity when running `getView`.

Answer (score 0):

Inside `ArrayAdapter.getView()`, use `getContext()` instead of `getActivity()`.

`getActivity()` can sometimes return `null` for a brief moment during an Activity rotation, whereas `getContext()` does not return `null` in the same situation. This problem happens on Android 4.2, 4.1 and below.